# Count with group by on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a postgresql type and a table

```sql
CREATE TYPE mem_status AS ENUM('waiting', 'active', 'expired');

CREATE TABLE mems (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  status mem_status NOT NULL
);
```

dataset

```sql
INSERT INTO mems(id, status) VALUES
  (1, 'active'), (2, 'active'), (3, 'expired');
```

I want to query counts that grouped by statuses. So I treid the query below.

```sql
WITH mem_statuses AS (
  SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL::mem_status)) AS status
)
SELECT m.status, count(1)
  FROM mems m
  RIGHT JOIN mem_statuses ms ON ms.status = m.status
  GROUP BY m.status;
```

But if there is no `waiting` mems, the result looks like below.

```
status     |  count  
================
NULL       |  1      <- problem
'active'   |  2
'expired'  |  1
```

I want to get result like this.

```
status     |  count  
================
'waiting'  |  0
'active'   |  2
'expired'  |  1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide some `INSERT` statements with sample data for `mems` that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `count(id)`:

```
WITH mem_statuses AS (
  SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL::mem_status)) AS status
)
SELECT ms.status, count(id)
  FROM mems m
  RIGHT JOIN mem_statuses ms ON ms.status = m.status
  GROUP BY ms.status;
```

or:

```
select status, count(id)
from unnest(enum_range(null::mem_status)) as status
left join mems using(status)
group by status


 status  | count 
---------+-------
 waiting |     0
 active  |     2
 expired |     1
(3 rows)
```

Per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) `count(expression)` gives

> number of input rows for which the value of expression is not null

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the join and aggregate a bit -

```
select ms.status, count(m.status)
from (select unnest(enum_range(null::mem_status))) as ms(status)
left join mems as m
  on ms.status = m.status
group by ms.status;
```